# jquery event does not work on ajax result like table

Tags: php, jquery, html

I created a table with radio button using ajax request. I want to get value from radio button by click event. But jquery event doesn't work on radio button.
my created table by ajax below

[image]

I have called this ajax result by bellow code

```
<code>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".todayTask").click(function(){
            var employee = '<?php echo trim($userID);?>';
            $.ajax({
                url: "ajax_call.php",
                type:"POST",
                data:{userID:employee},
                success: function(result){
                    $('#taskList').html(result);
            }});
        });
    });
</script>
</code>
```

Now I want to get value from radio button which stay in ajax result...
by below code but does not work...

```
<code>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#s").click(function(){
            var status_val = $(this).val();
            alert(status_val);
        });
    });
</script>
</code>
```

Comment: Post text, not pictures of text.

Comment: 1. IDs need to be unique. Change the `id="s"` to `data-type="start", data-type="pause"` and so on. 2. defer the click to the nearest container: `$('#taskList').on("click","input[name='s']",function() { console.log($(this).data("type")) });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your radio buttons are loaded via jquery, you need to use `on` event:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#taskList').on("click","#s", function(){
            var status_val = $(this).val();
            alert(status_val);
        });
    });
```

You need to also use a class `".s"` instead of an ID `"#s"`, because an ID needs to be unique, here is an example:

```
$('#taskList').on("click",".s", function(){
```

Comment: and use a class or the name since ID needs to be unique

Comment: @mplungjan you're right, i edited my answer

Comment: And use the nearest container to narrow down the event handling. In this case `#taskList`

Comment: Does not work yet....Please explain the reason @Flash

Comment: you replaced this line `$('#taskList').on("click","#s", function(){` in my answer with this line `$('#taskList').on("click",".s", function(){` right? if not, please do that

Comment: my edited code
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".tableShow").on("click",".s". function(){
            // var status_val = $(this).val();
            // alert(status_val);
            alert('hey');
        });
    });

Comment: also your radio buttons html should have a class like this `<input type="radio" name=""s" class="s"/>` , not an `id`

Comment: Yes, working now..... Thanks @ The Flash

Answer (score 0):

Bind your click event using `on`:

```
$("table").on("click","#s" ,function(){
    var status_val = $(this).val();
    alert(status_val);
});
```

**Note:** ID must me unique. So, either use `classes` or make sure you have unique `id`

Comment: Does not work yet.....#Sandeep Nayak